# Why does a continuous function on an open interval achieve either an absolute minimum or max but not both?

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

In my analysis textbook, there is an exercise that states:

> **Exercise.** Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on the interval $(0,1)$ to the real numbers, such that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 0$.
>
> Show $f$ achieves either an absolute minimum or an absolute maximum on $(0,1)$ but perhaps not both.

My question is, why is it 'perhaps not both'? For example, if I defined a function on $(0,2\pi)$ and let $f(x) = \sin(x)$, then wouldn't the function have both an absolute maximum and minimum?

Comment: where does it achieve it's minimum if the function was instead on the interval $(0,\pi)$?

Comment: That is why the problem is using the phrase 'perhaps', to allude the fact that some examples may achieve both types, while others may not. For an example which has only one of two types of extrema, consider the function $f(x) = x(1-x)$ on $(0, 1)$ and notice that $f$ has no minimum on $(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 3):

That “perhaps not both” means that *sometimes* such a function has a maximum but not a minimum or a minimum but no a maximum. Take $f(x)=x-x^2$, for instance. It has a maximum, but not a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function on an open interval with the given limits could be extended  to a continuous interval on the closed interval with $f(0)=f(1)=0$

Thus for the extended function you have to have both  absolute max or absolute minimum on the closed interval.

Now in case that one of them happens at the endpoint the other will be inside unless the function is a constant.